# Tumblr Logo off-center on popup

Tags: html, css

Simple question. Is there a way for me to center the Tumblr logo in the pop-up window? Currently it looks like this:

[image]

We have a simple tumblr share button that opens this window when clicked.

Thanks

Comment: Simple answer is no. This is a tumblr website and you can't touch it. You can iframe it and try to crop the logo out and add your own logo but it's too much of a hustle.

Comment: That's going to be a bug on Tumblr's end. Just like miro mentioned, it's their actual website. Maybe submit a possible bug report to them, also stating the browser and version you're on?

Comment: Can you share the full url in the picture? So we can check it too.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed a tumblr "bug"

It's happening because your pop-up window is too small (less than 900px)

Tumblr's page has a set min width

```
.l-header {
width: 900px!important;
```

You could either set the width of your pop up to 900 or report it to Tumblr

[Here's a link](https://www.tumblr.com/login?share_redirect_to=%2Fshare%2Flink%3Furl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flifehacker.com%252F5982818%252Fhow-to-create-a-budget%252Bfriendly-personalized-gift-with-tumblr%26name%3DGifts%253A%2BHow%2Bto%2BCreate%2BA%2BBudget-Friendly%252C%2BPersonalized%2BGift%2Bwith%2BTumblr%2528via%2B%2540Lifehacker%2529%26description%3DTumblr%2Bis%2Bknown%2Bas%2Ba%2Bsocial%2Bplatform%2Bdesigned%2Bfor%2Bsharing%252C%2Bre-sharing%252C%2Band%2Bgeneral%2Bpublic%2Bdisplay.%2BHowever%252C%2Bthere%2527s%2Ba%2Bless-used%2Bfeature%2Bthat%2Balso%2Bmakes%2Bit%2Ba%2Bwonderful%2Bplatform%2Bto%2Bcommunicate%2Bin%2Ba%2Bmuch%2Bmore%2Bpersonal%2Bway%25E2%2580%2594its%2Bprivate%2Bblog%2B) I tested with.

[image]